# How to split a notebook in wxpython?

Tags: python, split, wxpython

I have placed a notebook on a panel, notebook has 4 pages. Now I want to split each page horizontally. Top split will contain grid cells, and bottom will contain chart. How to do this?

Regards

Comment: Are you using `wx.aui.Notebook` with the `AUI_NB_TAB_SPLIT` style?

Comment: No, I use `notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)`

Comment: I don't see entries in the API for that http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxnotebook.html.  I'd suggest looking into the `aui` notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)

        splitter_window = wx.SplitterWindow(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(splitter_window, 'Splitter')
        panel1 = wx.Panel(splitter_window, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        wx.StaticText(panel1, label='Place Grid here')
        panel2 = wx.Panel(splitter_window, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        wx.StaticText(panel2, label='Place Chart here')
        splitter_window.SplitHorizontally(panel1, panel2, 50)

        p_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p_sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 7)
        panel.SetSizer(p_sizer)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```